The Solana transaction encountered a failure when submitted programmatically, yet it was successful through the Phantom wallet
I have created an VersionedTransaction with

SystemProgram.transfer -> Math.max(Math.floor((3e5 * priorityFee) / 1e6), 3e5)
ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice -> priorityFee
Swap instruction

It goes through on Phantom but failed when I try to push it through programmatically.

could you provide more details. what are the logs for the failure? what are you using to programmatically transfer the funds, TS, Rust, Python? And the code too

I use JavaScript to sent build and send this transaction also I used Solana web3 sdk to build and sent it.
